# Marshaling []interface{} in Go

Tags: json, go

```
type A struct {
    Id   uint32 `json:"id"`
}

type B struct {
    A
    Title           string `json:"title"`
}

type C struct {
    Id             uint32 `json:"id"`
    Name           string `json:"name"`
    Arrays         []interface{} `json:"arrays"`
}
```

Is this the correct way to marshal an array of interfaces?

Comment: look at the struct tag. That's where the problem lies

Answer (score 1):

Put arrays in double quotes json:"arrays"